# EXC_BAD_ACCESS caused when scrolling through

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios7

We are looking into this issue now for over a day and just can't find the cause for it. We have an App that runs fine on iOS6, but on iOS7 we get random crashes while scrolling through a UICollectionView that displays some custom UICollectionViewCells.

The crash itself happens at another place though, on

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and the stacktrace shows:

```
#0  0x39210b66 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x3102b042 in CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() ()
#2  0x3102adec in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
#3  0x33c2076c in IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc ()
#4  0x2f8afe6c in IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage ()
#5  0x2eb8db88 in __CFMachPortPerform ()
#6  0x2eb9877e in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#7  0x2eb9871a in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#8  0x2eb96ee6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#9  0x2eb01540 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#10 0x2eb01322 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#11 0x338052ea in GSEventRunModal ()
#12 0x313b81e4 in UIApplicationMain ()
#13 0x0001e69c in main
```

I somehow suspect that the problem is connected to the rendering of the UIImageViews inside the cells and to the reuse of the cells, but so far our trial and error didn't yeld any results (we also replaced now UICollectionView by thirdparty GMGridView but the issue stays the same). Activating NSZombies didn't change a thing (still crashing). On the Simulator the crash did not happen so far. we use ARC and don't use any malloc in our code.

What can we do to track that problem down?

Comment: You mention simulator ok. . When testing on device are you using debug or release mode? Some memory issues only show up in release configuration.

Comment: the problem happens on device in both, debug and release mode

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having a similar problem with a scroll view.

Comment: I think it's unity related - at least there is a workarround thread in the unity forums and our project uses unity